# Express JS api call to save data in DB is not throwing any of the error messages for data validations

Tags: node.js, express, node-sqlite3

I am testing out several api calls in express js using postman. In a database.js file i have created a table

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE customer (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name text, 
        address text,
        email text,
        dateOfBirth text,
        gender text,
        age INTEGER,
        cardHolderName text,
        cardNumber INTEGER,
        expiryDate text,
        cvv INTEGER,
        timeStamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        )`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            // Table already created
        } else {
            // Table just created, creating some rows
            var insert = 'INSERT INTO customer (name, address, email, dateOfBirth, gender, age, cardHolderName, cardNumber, expiryDate, cvv, timeStamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
            db.run(insert, ["A.D. Lakith Dharmasiri", "No 324/A ,R.A De Mel Road, Colombo", "lakith@gmail.com", "25/2/1991", "Female", 28, "A.D.L.Dharmasiri", 244767656777, "12/24", 244, "2022-12-08 12:40:00"])

        }
    })
```

I'm using a POST api call to send some info into the DB.

```
app.post("/api/customers/", (req, res, next) => {

try {
    var errors = []
    var mailformat = /^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.w{2,3})+$/;
    if (!req.body) {
        errors.push("An invalid input");
    }
    if (!req.body.email.match(mailformat)) {
        errors.push("You have entered an invalid email address!"); 
    }
    if (req.body.cardNumber.length != 12) {
        errors.push("You have entered an invalid card number!"); 
    }

    const { name, 
        address,
        email,
        dateOfBirth,
        gender,
        age,
        cardHolderName,
        cardNumber,
        expiryDate,
        cvv,
        timeStamp
    } = req.body;

    var sql = 'INSERT INTO customer (name, address, email, dateOfBirth, gender, age, cardHolderName, cardNumber, expiryDate, cvv, timeStamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    var params = [name, address, email, dateOfBirth, gender, age, cardHolderName, cardNumber, expiryDate, cvv, timeStamp]
    db.run(sql, params, function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({ "error": err.message })
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({
                "message": "success",
                "data": req.body,
                "id": this.lastID
            })
        }

    });
} catch (E) {
    res.status(400).send(E);
}
```

});

There are some validations to check before saving any data.

- Checking if response body is null
- Checking for email validation
- Checking for number of digits in card number

I'm also attempting to send the current timestamp automatically with the request body.
When i try to test the api using postman, for empty body i get a 400 but without any error message and any other data validations are not checked and data gets saved.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `errors` other than adding adding messages to it.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Thanks for pointing that out